# JQuery fade to different headers on single page website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a single page website with a fixed navigation. Within the navigation there are two containers, the one on the left contains a series of headers that change as you click the links on the right. I am setting the display on each of the classes containing the headers to 'none' and attempting to display them with Jquery when you click the links on the right. But nothing I am trying is working. Is it possible to get a smooth transition using the fade element and Jquery to achieve a series of headers that change upon clicking the links?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="single-page-nav">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <div style="max-width: 1200px; min-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;">
            <div style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 40px; z-index: 999999;">
                <a href="#section-1" class="mainNavLnk mainNav001">Home</a>
                <a href="#section-2" class="mainNavLnk mainNav002">About Us</a>
                <a href="#section-3" class="mainNavLnk mainNav003">Practice Areas</a>
                <a href="#section-4" class="mainNavLnk mainNav004">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <div class="header001"><h1>Doug Peterson</h1></div>
            <div class="header002"><h1>About Us.</h1></div>
            <div class="header003"><h1>Practice Areas.</h1></div>
            <div class="header004"><h1>Contact.</h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav"></div>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>                        
    </div>
</div>
```

Help the student.

Comment: You'd need to show your Javascript/JQuery, but I'd be pretty sure you problem is with the absolute and relative position declarations. These shouldn't be necessary for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic working version of what it sounds like you want. You will need to style it to look the way you want, but the behavior (showing/hiding divs on click of the menu) is there. You might think about changing the naming scheme for hrefs and divs to make it easier to select the header div based on the link clicked.

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">     </script>
<style>
    .header{
     display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var selected = '';
        $( "a", "#headerLinks" )
            .on( "click", function(){
                var divCls = ".header00" + $( this ).attr( "href" ).substring($( this ).attr( "href" ).length -1 ); 
                if( selected.length > 0 ){
                    $( selected, "#headers" )
                        .hide('fade', function(){
                            $( divCls, "#headers" )
                                .show('fade');                           
                        });
                }else{
                    $( divCls, "#headers"  )
                      .show('fade');   
                }
                selected = divCls;
            });


     });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="single-page-nav">
    <div class="nav-container">
        <div style="max-width: 1200px; min-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;">
            <div id="headerLinks" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 40px; z-index: 999999;">
                <a href="#section-1" class="mainNavLnk mainNav001">Home</a>
                <a href="#section-2" class="mainNavLnk mainNav002">About Us</a>
                <a href="#section-3" class="mainNavLnk mainNav003">Practice Areas</a>
                <a href="#section-4" class="mainNavLnk mainNav004">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left" id="headers">
            <div class="header header001"><h1>Doug Peterson</h1></div>
            <div class="header header002"><h1>About Us.</h1></div>
            <div class="header header003"><h1>Practice Areas.</h1></div>
            <div class="header header004"><h1>Contact.</h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav"></div>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>                        
    </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```